How to sequentially run SQL scripts on a local database cross platform?
I've written 5 sequential SQL scripts that I've been running in 'DB Browser for SQLite.app' on my Mac to update a local database file, and I was looking for a quicker, single button solution and a way to share this the tool others.  I was thinking of using Chrome's File System Access API so it could be done in a cross-platform browser using HTML and Javascript.  I wanted to keep it simple, not something online, and not requiring other people to install anything to get it to run.  I'm having trouble finding any online resources for this, as it seems not many want to do this, or they tend to write it in C+ or Python (I'm still not too familiar with those).  Again, I'm looking for a solution that's easily shared, and easy to make cross-platform for Windows and Mac.  Any suggestions?

Keeping it simple is to make a bash/sh script, detecting either windows or mac is trivial, the button could simply be the icon they click to run it

I'm not very familiar with bash, either.  I'd also need the user to locate their local database...could that be done in a bash script?

Also, if I wrote a bash script, wouldn't some Windows users have to install something to get it work?  I was hoping I wouldn't have to write something in 2 languages to make it cross platform.

To use SQLite you'll to need a client, all os's will need to install something, it's unclear, why someone would use your tool to run sequential sql queries, if they not already have sqlite installed with a specific reason to run it.

It's a type of home media server similar to Plex, where you run the app and manage the content through a browser.  I wanted to re-organise some of the media which took way too much manual labour, so I was able to do it more quickly with these 5 SQL scripts.  A bit cumbersome to copy and paste every time, so I was wondering how to make it easier and how to share it with others who have the same home media server.
